# Проблемы со считыванием с клавиактуры _getch()

Tags: c++, c, разработка-игр

Всем доброго дня. Пишу простенькую игру. Смысл в том, что гг ходит по полю, двигая коробки, ища выход. Дошел до места где собственно описываю перемещения гг. Считываю с клавиатуры с помощью _getch(), но при этом ничего не происходит. персонаж стоит на месте. Вот код.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Include libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/**********************************************************************/
//Game setting 
const int RowsCount = 10;
const int ColumnsCount = 15;

const unsigned char SymbolHero = 2;
const unsigned char SymbolWall = 177;
const unsigned char SymbolBox = 254;
const unsigned char SymbolExit = 176;

const unsigned char LevelData0[RowsCount][ColumnsCount + 1 ] = {

    "#####2#########",
    "#  X   #   X ##",
    "# X ### X  #  #",
    "#X X  X  ## X #",
    "# X    ##  #  #",
    "#######    # X#",
    "#   X   XX #X #",
    "# 1  # # X   ##",
    "#    #   X X  #",
    "###############",

};



//********************************************************************//

// Logic  variables

bool isGameActive = true;
unsigned char LevelData[RowsCount][ColumnsCount];
int HeroRow = 0;
int HeroColumn = 0;

//********************************************************************//
// Functions 

void SetupSystem()
{
    //srand(time(0));
}

void Initialise()
{

    //Load Level one 
    for (int r = 0; r < RowsCount; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < ColumnsCount; c++)
        {
            unsigned char symbol = LevelData0[r][c];

            switch (symbol)
            {
                //Wall
            case '#': { LevelData[r][c] = SymbolWall;
                break; }
                //Hero
            case '1': { LevelData[r][c] = SymbolHero;
                break; }
                // Exit
            case '2': { LevelData[r][c] = SymbolExit;
                break; }
                // Box
            case 'X': { LevelData[r][c] = SymbolBox;
                break; }
                // Other symbols
            default: { LevelData[r][c] = symbol;
                break; }



            }

        }
    }

}

void Render()
{
    system("cls");

    printf("\n\n\t");
    for (int r = 0; r < RowsCount; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < ColumnsCount; c++)
        {
            unsigned char symbol = LevelData[r][c];
            printf("%c", symbol);

        }
        printf("\n\t");
    }


}
void MoveHeroTo (int row, int column)
{
    unsigned char destinationCell = LevelData[row][column];
    bool canMoveToCell = false;

    switch (destinationCell) {
        //Empty cell
    case ' ': {canMoveToCell = true; break; }

              // Exit cell
    case SymbolExit: {isGameActive = false; break; } 

                     //BOX
    case SymbolBox: 
            {
                    // Calculate hero move direction
                int heroDirectionR = row - HeroRow;
                int heroDirectionC = column - HeroColumn;

                    //check for empty space behiend the box
                if (LevelData[row + heroDirectionR][column + heroDirectionC] == ' ')
                {
                    canMoveToCell = true;
                    //remove box simbol from prev position
                    LevelData[row][column] = ' ';
                    // set the box to new position 
                    LevelData[row + heroDirectionC][column + heroDirectionC] = SymbolBox;
                    break;
                }
            }
                            }   
}

void Update()
{
    unsigned char inputChar = _getch ();
    inputChar = tolower(inputChar);

    switch (inputChar)
    {
        // Up
    case 'w':
    {
        MoveHeroTo(HeroRow - 1, HeroColumn);
        break;
    }

    // Down
    case 's':
    {
        MoveHeroTo(HeroRow + 1, HeroColumn);
        break;
    }

    // Left
    case 'a':
    {
        MoveHeroTo(HeroRow, HeroColumn - 1);
        break;
    }

    // Right
    case 'd':
    {
        MoveHeroTo(HeroRow, HeroColumn + 1);
        break;
    }

    // Restart level
    case 'r':
    {
        Initialise();
        break;
    }
    }
}

void Shutdown()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\tPress any key to continue...");
    _getch();
}


int main()
{
    SetupSystem();
    Initialise();

    do
    {
        Render();
        Update();
    } while (isGameActive);
    Shutdown();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Отладчик в руки и смотрите почему же он стоит на месте.

Comment: если бы я понимал как это посмотреть, я бы тут не спрашивал

Comment: Начните с отладки более простых программ.

Answer (score 1):

`HeroRow` и `HeroColumn` нигде не меняются.

И как я понимаю, `destinationCell` в данном случае никогда не равен ни какому варианту из `switch` в функции `MoveHeroTo`.

Я попробовал другую карту и изменил `HeroRow` и `HeroColumn`, и все сработало хорошо, для одного шага.

```
"#####2#########",
"#  X   #   X ##",
"# X ### X  #  #",
"#X X  X  ## X #",
"# X    ##  #  #",
"               ",
"#             #",
"#      1     ##",
"#             #",
"###############",

HeroRow = 3 и HeroColumn = 3
```

Comment: Напрямую - нет, но в функции Update() обращаюсь через switch

Comment: HeroRow и HeroColumn всегда равны 0, поскольку они не меняются нигде.
И как я понимаю, destinationCell в данном случае никогда не равен ни какому варианту из swithc в функции MoveHeroTo. 
Вам определено следует последовать совету Владимира Мартьянова и воспользоваться и научиться отлаживать программу.